# Pair Symfony5 with Phaser.js

Tags: css, frontend, phaser-framework, back, symfony5

Framework: Phaser.js 3, Symfony 5
Langage: Javascript , HTML5,Twig,CSS3

Hello, I am learning Phaser.js version 3 and I wanted to know if it is possible to link a project made with Phaser.js version 3 with a project made with Symfony 5 to make a website. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since phaser is a pure javascript framework. the answer is **yes**. you just have to link the right file(s). There are many project templates for phaser out there, like https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-project-template.

**BUT** if you don't want to use nodejs, webpack,... and just keep it simple.
Just link to the phaser framework(`phaser.min.js`), (the framewok is one single file you can download here https://phaser.io/download/stable), and create your game in the html page/ twig template ([like in the example](https://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started-phaser3/part5)) or in a seperate file javascript, that you also link after the `phaser.min.js`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's going to be easier for me to create my website and my game

Comment: @MikaMikashu your well come, happy that it helped. if it answers your question, could you accept the answer, by clicking the check sign unter the voting arrows, so that it turns green. that would be great. thanks

Comment: It's good it's done